# How to read Gitlab (.gitlab-ci.yml ) environment variable from Spring Boot code?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I am trying to read an environment variable is being set from within Gitlab configuration when the application is being built, I am doing this for achieving that purpose:

I setup a variable in the application.properties.yml of my spring boot app:

```
sf:
 apiKey: $SF_API_KEY
```

In the .gitlab-ci.yml, I defined the variable to be set, as follows:

```
variables:
  SF_API_KEY: $SF_API_KEY
```

all I want, is to be able to read that variable from within one of my services, as the below code depicts:

```
@Service
class MyService(@Value("\${sf.apiKey}") val apiKey: String)
{

 fun doSomething(){

 //i am seeing the variable is being set by gitlab in the build logs but 
 // it is not being read here properly 
 var result = apiKey;

 logger.info { "***check apiKey:  $apiKey" }
  //This line lgs $SF_API_KEY as a value of my variable, but not the 
  // real value

 }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try (note the `{}` around `SF_API_KEY`):

```
sf:
 apiKey: ${SF_API_KEY}
```

Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties) where this placeholder notation is detailed.